# Cannot display image (form JSON) in detail activity from search reasult?

Tags: android, json, image, universal-image-loader

I spent three days and didn’t find working solution to display image in detail view. 
Because I use search view I have to use more difficult way which doesn't work. 
I’m using Universal Image Loader in ListActivity but have no idea how to implement it in DetailView.
TextView text is displaying correct in DetailView.
I see while debuging, url of the image in ’extras’ (or ’intent’) in ’mMap’ value, but can’t display it.
’ flag’ variable is null. 'flagImg' doesn't constain image url.
I tryied with getParacetable, Bitmap, but I always get null in flag value.

ListActivity:

```
    public ListAdapter(Context context, List<MovieModel.Descriptions> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater.from(context));
        this.arrayList = new ArrayList<MovieModel.Descriptions>();
        this.arrayList.addAll(items);
    } 
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("flag",(items.get(position).getImage()));
        intent.putExtra("getInfo",(items.get(position).getInfo()));
        context.startActivity(intent);
        }
        });
        return view;
        }

public void filter(String charText){
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        items.clear();;
        if(charText.length() == 0) {
        items.addAll(arrayList);
        }else{
        for(MovieModel.Descriptions wp : arrayList){
        if(wp.getTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))
        items.add(wp);
        }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

In Detail Activity

```
     int flag;
        int send;
        // recovering data
        Intent i = getIntent();
        info = i.getStringExtra("getInfo");
        detInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
        detInfo.setText(info);

        flag = i.getIntExtra("flag", send);
        flagImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.detailImg);
        flagImg.setImageResource(flag);

// Two of 9 solutions I used:
// bitmap is null
//        flagImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.detailImg);
//        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) i.getParcelableExtra("flag");
//        flagImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

//  bmp is null:
//        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
//        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.getParcelable("flag");
//        detImg.setImageBitmap(bmp);


            // How add this image to Universal Image Loader ?
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(flagImg.setImageResource(flag),flagImg, new ImageLoadingListener() {...
```

Comment: You are mentionig in your question that you want an url of ima but where did you download image? If you are passing by intent an url of image, in your `DetailActivity` you are reciving it as an `int` not as a `String`. If you have na url of image you have to download that image and pass to `ImageView`

Comment: More code shows this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46911971/listview-in-the-first-activity-listview-in-the-second-activity-nested-json-no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suppose that you are passing correct url via intent so in your `DetailActivity`:

```
String flag;
flag = i.getStringExtra("flag");
flagImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.detailImg);
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.displayImage(flag, flagImg);
```

Comment: Yupi, you are amazing! Thank you very much !!! I see I can't vote because I have not enought reputation points. But I think it will be very helpfull for someone who point the same problem. To complete your answer:  before last line we should ad:  flagImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.detailImg);

Comment: You are welcome. If helped you can mark as correct answer.

Comment: I want mark your helpful answer but I can't because I need 15 points of reputation and I have only 9. Sorry.